# Render custom Joomla profile Form

Tags: joomla-3.x, registration, profile

We are create a joomla registration form using Phonegap (+webservices).  The user hit the 'Register' button on the mobile and a request hits the Joomla server.

Now the Joomla server has to identify all the custom profiles and send them as a Form or XML or something back so that the mobile client can render the data on the screen.

Not sure this makes any sense... Do we have any method so that it can return the form or is there any simpler way to do??

Answer (score 2):

Finally got a workaround.

```
require_once JPATH_BASE/components/com_users/modes/registration.php

$obj = new UsersModelRegistration();
$form = $obj->getForm()->getXML();
```

This gives the complete form which includes the core registration form with all other custom profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom plugin for your Joomla site and utilize the onAfterUserSave method to return any type of string you want.